# Function with variable-length nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

`FromPolarCoordinates` has a very nice feature: if you supply several points, e. g. `{{r1,phi1},{r2,phi2},...}`, it will return a nested list with the converted cartesian coordinates in one go.

Right now, I have a helper function that is just the name-abbreviated form of the built-in function:

```
FromPolar[{r_, \[Phi]_}] := FromPolarCoordinates[{r, \[Phi]}]
```

The obvious drawback is that I have to call `FromPolar` once for every list (= point) separately. Additionally, it would be helpful to sort out all the points where the radius equals zero: for each element in the nested list, check if the first entry is zero, if yes, return `{0,0}`.

Something like `FromPolar[{r_, \[Phi]_}] := If[r == 0, {0, 0}, FromPolarCoordinates[{r, \[Phi]}]]`, but for several point at once.

Comment: It's probably safer to literally identify the symbols: `ClearAll[FromPolar]; FromPolar = FromPolarCoordinates;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so if you were just using an abbreviation, I'd literally identify the symbols via `Set`: `FromPolar = FromPolarCoordinates;`. But since you want to modify it slightly, we can add another definition. To be careful, though, we want to make sure we only `Map` (`/@`) over lists of lists, and NOT over lists of other kinds of expressions. For that we'll check `r` and `\[Phi]` are not `List`s via `Except`.

```
ClearAll[FromPolar];

FromPolar[l : {{_, _} ...}] := FromPolar /@ l

FromPolar[{r : Except[_List], \[Phi] : Except[_List]}] :=
    If[r == 0, {0, 0}, FromPolarCoordinates[{r, \[Phi]}]]
```

What we need to watch out for is when the argument is a pair of lists, e.g. `{{0,1},{1,1}}`; without `Except`, Mathematica would try to put the list `{0,1}` in for `r_` and `{1,1}` in for `\[Phi]_`.

Technically, though, we didn't *have* to use `Except`; we could have just evaluated the `l : {{_, _} ...}` definition *first* and Mathematica would always check to see if the argument is a list of lists first, but this is a bit safer (at the cost of a little overhead).

---

You also expressed interest in a one-definition form! A typical way might be to use `f[arg_] := Switch[arg, patt1, val1, patt2, val2, ...]` or `Replace`. Here's a nifty way to do that with level specification in `Map`. When unspecified, `Map` (`/@`) assumes that you are applying its first argument to every element on exactly level `1`, e.g. `f /@ {a,b,c}` is syntactic sugar for `Map[f, {a,b,c}, {1}]`, and yields `{f[a],f[b],f[c]}`. (The list brackets in `{1}` mean (by convention) "exactly", as opposed to "up through" without them.) But you can also map at exactly level `0`; `Map[f, {a,b,c}, {0}]` gets you `f[{a,b,c}]`.

We also use `Apply` (`@@`), which takes an expression `f` and replaces the head of the second argument with it. E.g. `f @@ g[a,b]` (equivalently `Apply[f, g[a,b]]`) yields `f[a,b]`, and likewise (since `{a,b,c}` is syntactic sugar for `List[a,b,c]`) `f @@ {a,b,c}` yields `f[a,b,c]`. `Apply` applied to a single argument, e.g. `Apply[f]`, is the operator form of `Apply`: apply *that* to an expression and you get the normal `Apply`, i.e. `Apply[f][expr]` yields `Apply[f, expr]`.

Finally, we'll use anonymous functions. For clarity we can use e.g. `{a,b} |-> a + b` for an anonymous function with two formal parameters that adds its arguments; we could also equivalently use `#1 + #2 &`. I'll use the latter for brevity.

So we can check if we should `Map` or not based on the argument pattern, then feed that into the level spec. Note that `Boole` converts `True`/`False` into `1`/`0`.

```
ClearAll[FromPolar];

FromPolar[arg : ({{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}...} | {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ})] :=
  Map[Apply[If[#1 == 0, {0,0}, FromPolarCoordinates[{#1, #2}]] &],
    arg,
    {Boole[MatchQ[arg, {___List}]]}
  ]
```

I didn't bother matching the full pattern in the `Boole`, since we know that if we've gotten that far, we must be in one of these two cases.

You'll notice I do a little more argument pattern-matching here to ensure we're using numeric values. When you pattern-match with `?`, you're moving outside the pattern matcher and bringing in the main evaluator, so it's a bit more expensive than our other pattern. But it is a bit safer. Up to you if you want that!

You can also replace `Apply[...]` with simply `If[First[#] == 0, {0,0}, FromPolarCoordinates[#]] &`. This is in fact a little faster! But `Apply` is very useful, and good to get experience with (as with `Map`). As you can see, there are lots of ways to extract and address parts of expressions in Mathematica: with pattern matching, positionally, and structurally/functionally (e.g. head replacement (`Apply`) and `Map`). It's not always immediate which will be fastest, but generally the last and first are considered the best and most readable style. Sometimes, though, you really just want the `First` element. :)

Let me know if you're not familiar with anything here! I'd be happy to explain :)

*Aside*

By the way, if you're doing numeric stuff, you might also find it convenient to automatically put `\[Phi]` in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$, otherwise `FromPolarCoordinates` will throw an error. For some reason `FromPolarCoordinates` doesn't do this automatically! Fixing this means replacing `\[Phi]` in `FromPolarCoordinates[{r, \[Phi]}]` in the second definition with something like `Mod[\[Phi], 2 Pi, Pi]`—except that puts it into the range $[-\pi, \pi)$, and we need $(-\pi, \pi]$. So, this is weird: thanks to the symmetry of the interval, we can actually handle this by negating things twice, and use `-Mod[-\[Phi], 2 Pi, -Pi]` in place of `\[Phi]` in our call to `FromPolarCoordinates`.

Comment: I thought that `FromPolar[list : {{_, _} ...}] := FromPolarCoordinates[list]` was enough to walk the entire nested list, but it seems to be missing the map command. How can I coalesce the `Map` and the function definition?

Comment: @user2286339 There are two things here: `FromPolarCoordinates`, under the hood, likely has two definitions for different argument patterns, just like our `FromPolar` here—and likewise, in the `{{_,_}...}` argument case, it likely `Map`s itself (or an internal version of itself) over the argument `l`. `Map` (`/@`) is what you want to use to "walk" a list! :) Second, you don't want map the function `FromPolarCoordinates` over your list—you want to map the function which [checks if the first coordinate is `0` via `If`, and only if not, applies `FromPolarCoordinates`] over the argument list.

Comment: @user2286339 let me know if this answers your question—I might have misinterpreted.

Comment: Your code sample has two definitions - the one with the `Map` followed by the actual implementation. What I am looking for is how I can merge them, if possible.

Comment: @user2286339 yes, it's quite customary in mathematica to attach more than one definition to a symbol! the argument patterns are checked each time it's applied, and the definition of whichever matches is called. it's possible to make them just one by checking the argument pattern with a `Switch`, or maybe with a `Replace` for better extraction of expression parts, but is there a particular reason you want to do this? multiple definitions is typically considered better style afaik.

Comment: My motivation is to have everything in a single "place", or brevity if you prefer. But that can wait if I have some more experience with MMA.

Comment: @user2286339 I see. (you could technically put these definitions on the same line and separate them with `;`, but I get the sense that's not what you want :) ) Note that using multiple definitions can in some cases (not all) be faster, as mathematica creates an optimized dispatch table for the replacements. I thought of another way though, which doesn't use `Switch` or `Replace`—I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: @user2286339 ok, edited. :)

Comment: `If[#[[1]] == 0, {0, 0}, FromPolarCoordinates[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}]] & /@{{1,0},{2,Pi/2},...}` seems to be functionally equivalent to your solution - you may want to include it for future reference or side-by-side comparison.

Comment: @user2286339 That's already included in the body under the code block as the option to replace `Apply[...]` with `If[First[#] == 0, {0, 0}, FromPolarCoordinates[#]] &`; no need to reconstruct the the argument `#` (of the form `{r, \[Phi]}` as `{#[[1]], #[[2]]}`! (and generally `First` is a slight bit faster than `[[1]]`.) Note that that alone doesn't take care of the single-argument `FromPolar[{r, \[Phi]}]` case, though.

Comment: A few follow-up questions - let's move to chat

Comment: How can I find out which commands run faster than the others? I suppose you didn't use `Timing`. Is there some MMA optimization guide for this?